# Can I install ubuntu on my desktop? If so, which version is more suitable?

Tags: 12.04

My desktop specification is:

- intel(R)Core(TM)2 Duo cpu
- E7200 @ 2.53Ghz
- 1.99 GB RAM

I would like to know if my system is eligible for installing ubuntu operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sure you can! Ubuntu can run on almost everything including old Celeron processors (700MHz). If your system can run Windows or OSX then it can definitely handle Ubuntu much much more better.

Which version to choose is more a choice of your own. But I van help you narrow it down to two choices Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10.

12.04 works fine and has the best support. It will still be updated until april 2017.

13.10 is the newest version with more features but it has more bugs. It will be supported for less then a year.

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu can run even on the most under-powered systems, you on the other hand, have a very capable one.

I would suggest, judging that you are a beginner, installing Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, as it is a long term support version, it will most likely support all your hardware.
Though, if you like to always have the latest and greatest, go with Ubuntu 13.10.